# Military time zones using JSR 310 (DateTime API)

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, java-time

I'm using the JSR 310 DateTime API* in my application, and I need to parse and format military date times (known as DTG or "date time group").

The format I'm parsing looks like this (using `DateTimeFormatter`):

```
"ddHHmm'Z' MMM yy" // (ie. "312359Z DEC 14", for new years eve 2014)
```

This format is fairly easy to parse as described above. The problem arises when the dates contains a different time zone than 'Z' (Zulu time zone, same as UTC/GMT), for example 'A' (Alpha, UTC+1:00) or 'B' (Bravo, UTC+2:00). See [Military time zones](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/military) for the full list.

How can I parse these time zones? Or in other words, what can I put in the format above other than the literal 'Z' to have it parse all zones correctly? I have tried using `"ddHHmmX MMM yy"`, `"ddHHmmZ MMM yy"` and `"ddHHmmVV MMM yy"`, but none of them work (all will throw `DateTimeParseException: Text '312359A DEC 14' could not be parsed at index 6` for the example above, when parsing). Using a single `V` in the format is not allowed (`IllegalArgumentException` when trying to instantiate `DateTimeFormatter`).

Edit: It seems that the symbol `z` could have worked, if it wasn't for the issue below.

I should also mention that I have created a `ZoneRulesProvider` with the all the named zones and correct offset. I have verified that these are registered correctly using the SPI mechanism, and my `provideZoneIds()` method is invoked as expected. Still won't parse. As a side issue (Edit: this now seems to be the main issue), single character time zone ids (or "regions") other than 'Z' are not  allowed by the API.

For example:

```
ZoneId alpha = ZoneId.of("A"); // boom
```

Will throw `DateTimeException: Invalid zone: A` (without even accessing my rules provider to see if it exists).

Is this an oversight in the API? Or am I doing something wrong?

---

*) Actually, I'm using Java 7 and [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), but I don't think that matters for this question.

PS: My current workaround is to use 25 different `DateTimeFormatter`s with literal zone id (ie. `"ddHHmm'A' MMM yy"`, `"ddHHmm'B' MMM yy"`, etc), use a `RegExp` for extracting the zone id, and delegating to the correct formatter based on the zone. Zone ids in the provider are named "Alpha", "Bravo", etc to allow `ZoneId.of(...)` to find the zones. It works. But it's not very elegant, and I'm hoping there's a better solution.

Comment: Have you tried `V` for zone-id in the format string (i.e. `"ddHHmmV MMM yy"`)? AFAIK `'Z'` means just `Z` character. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Yes, I understand that `'Z'` is a literal and is not interpreted by the parser. `Z` (unquoted) is a symbol though (but doesn't work) . And yes, I tried `V`. It gives a different error though... `IllegalArgumentException: Pattern letter count must be 2: V` when trying to create the formatter. Using `VV`, I'm back to the "...could not be parsed at index 6" exception while parsing. Thanks anyway! :-)

Comment: @PavelHoral Actually, it seems the "correct" symbol is `z` (lowercase)... This seems to parse the zone correctly, but of course it blows up as the single letter zone is not allowed.. :-P "`...could not be parsed: Invalid zone: A`". I will update the question...

Comment: Regarding `ZoneRulesProvider` - can you share that? Were you registering that correctly (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html - sorry if that is noobish question :))?

Comment: @PavelHoral I'll have to check if I'm allowed to, but it's pretty trivial. I have a `public final class MyZoneRulesProvider extends ZoneRulesProvider` (and implementing the required methods) in the package `com.example.datetime` + a file `/META-INF/services/org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesProvider` containing exactly one line: `com.example.datetime.MyZoneRulesProvider` (the fully qualified name of the provider class) on class path (ie. in the same JAR as the provider class).

Comment: That sounds correct...

Comment: @PavelHoral Yes, I have verified that the intended SPI methods are invoked and that my zone rules are applied (I can do ´ZoneId alpha = ZoneId.of("Alpha");` and get the desired result).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `java.time`, the `ZoneId` is limited to be 2 characters or more. Ironically, this was to reserve space to allow the military IDs to be added in a future JDK release if it proved to be heavily in demand. As such, sadly your provider will not work, and there is no way to create the `ZoneId` instances you desire with those names.

The parsing problem is soluble once you consider working with `ZoneOffset` instead of `ZoneId` (and given that military zones are fixed offsets, that is a good way to look at the problem).

The key is the method `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendText(TemporalField, Map)` which allows a numeric field to be formatted and parsed as text, using text of your choice. And `ZoneOffset` is a numeric field (the value being the total number of seconds in the offset).

I this example, I've setup the mapping for `Z`, `A` and `B`, but you'd need to add them all. Otherwise, the code is pretty simple, setting up a formatter that can print and parse the military time (use `OffsetDateTime` for date and time).

```
Map<Long, String> map = ImmutableMap.of(0L, "Z", 3600L, "A", 7200L, "B");
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("HH:mm")
    .appendText(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, map)
    .toFormatter();
System.out.println(OffsetTime.now().format(f));
System.out.println(OffsetTime.parse("11:30A", f));
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitively a much cleaner and more elegant solution! Tested and works very well with my format.

Comment: PS: I'm currently converting all date/times internally to Zulu and use `ZonedDateTime` rather than `OffsetDateTime`. I'm used to Joda, but this is my first project using JSR 310. Is there a good reason for using ODT over ZDT (I realize you wanted to merge these classes at some point... :-) ?

Comment: ODT is simpler and can have no DST issues. Its the standard network ISO08601 format too. Otherwise the classes are very similar. Use whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 3):

**The behaviour of java.time-package (JSR-310) with respect to support of zone ids is as specified** - see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html). Explicit citation of the relevant section (other IDs are just considered as offset-ids in format "Z", "+hh:mm", "-hh:mm" or "UTC+hh:mm" etc.):

> A region-based ID must be of two or more characters

The requirement of having at least two characters is also implemented in the source code of class [ZoneRegion](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/time/ZoneRegion.java) before any loading of timezone data starts:

```
/**
 * Checks that the given string is a legal ZondId name.
 *
 * @param zoneId  the time-zone ID, not null
 * @throws DateTimeException if the ID format is invalid
 */
private static void checkName(String zoneId) {
    int n = zoneId.length();
    if (n < 2) {
       throw new DateTimeException("Invalid ID for region-based ZoneId, invalid format: " + zoneId);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char c = zoneId.charAt(i);
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') continue;
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') continue;
        if (c == '/' && i != 0) continue;
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9' && i != 0) continue;
        if (c == '~' && i != 0) continue;
        if (c == '.' && i != 0) continue;
        if (c == '_' && i != 0) continue;
        if (c == '+' && i != 0) continue;
        if (c == '-' && i != 0) continue;
        throw new DateTimeException("Invalid ID for region-based ZoneId, invalid format: " + zoneId);
    }
}
```

This explains why it is not possible with JSR-310/Threeten to write an expression like `ZoneId.of("A")`. The letter Z works because it is specified as well in ISO-8601 as in JSR-310 to represent the zero offset.

**The workaround you have found is fine within the scope of JSR-310 which does NOT support military timezones.** Consequently you will not find any format support for it (just study the class `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` - every processing of format pattern symbols is routed to the builder). The only vague idea I have got was to implement a specialized `TemporalField` representing a military timezone offset. But the implementation is (if possible at all) with certainty more complex than your workaround.

**Another more suitable workaround is just string preprocessing.** Since you work with a fixed format expecting the military letter always at the same position in input, you can simply do this:

```
String input = "312359A Dec 14";
String offset = "";

switch (input.charAt(6)) {
  case 'A':
    offset = "+01:00";
    break;
  case 'B':
    offset = "+02:00";
    break;
  //...
  case 'Z':
    offset = "Z";
    break;
  default:
    throw new ParseException("Wrong military timezone: " + input, 6);
}
input = input.substring(0, 6) + offset + input.substring(7);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddHHmmVV MMM yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
ZonedDateTime odt = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, formatter);
System.out.println(odt);
// output: 2014-12-31T23:59+01:00
```

Notes:

- I have used "Dec" instead of "DEC", otherwise the parser will complain. If your input really has capital letters then you might use the builder method [parseCaseInsensitive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseCaseInsensitive--).
- **The other answer using the field `OffsetSeconds` is the better answer** with regards to the parsing problem and has also got my upvote (have overlooked this feature). It is not better because it puts the burden on the user to define a mapping from military zone letters to offsets - like my suggestion with string preprocessing. **But it is better because it enables using the builder-methods `optionalStart()` and `optionalEnd()` so optional time zone letters A, B, ... can be handled.** See also the comment of OP about optional zone ids.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I think I'll mark this as the correct answer, as what I want to do seems impossible given the current spec/implementation (I did file an issue with the threetenbp project, awaiting feedback).

Comment: Re. string preprocessing and case sensitivity, yes, I am aware of that. The actual format I use for parsing is more complex than what I have shown. The zone id is optional (if omitted, Z is assumed) and also spaces are optional (meaning `charAt(6)` might be the A in Apr...). I'll stick to my regexp based solution. I'll look into using regexp replacement though, it might work! And the `ZoneRulesProvider` I made is perhaps redundant, I could just have used `ZoneOffset`s directly. Anyway, thank you for a good and thorough answer! :-)